# Typescript tsc getting 'never' error in es6 promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, tsc

I'm migrating a simple JavaScript node module and server code that utilizes it to TypeScript, But something really strange happens somehow...

I used promise chaining syntax below:

```
api.Promise1().then(resultOfPromise1 =>
       resultOfPromise1.isGood() ?
         api.Promise2() :
         Promise.reject({some:"errorInfo"})
       ).then(resultOfPromise2 => {
         resultOfPromise2.doSomeThing();
       }).catch(e => {
          // Handle exception.
       });
```

And tsconfig.json is like below:

```
{
        "compilerOptions": {
            "lib": [
                "es2015","es2016.array.include","es2017.string","es2015.promise"
            ]
        }
}
```

with codes above, tsc gave me a strange error that claims resultOfPromise2 can be  'never' type :

```
error TS2339: Property 'doSomeThing' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

But even with this error emerges, the compiled .js functions fine as expected.

Can this be a tsc issue or there's something I've lost?

**UPDATE** Here is reduced version of the code which compiles without any errors:

```
class SqlResult{
    result: string;
}

function doSqlQuery(query: string): Promise<SqlResult>{
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                res({ result: "123" });
            } else {
                rej(new Error("SQL "));
            }
        }, 20);
    });
} 

class Api{
    Promise1():Promise<string>{
        return doSqlQuery("").then(result => Promise.resolve(result.result))
    }
    Promise2():Promise<string>{
        return doSqlQuery("").then(result => Promise.resolve(result.result))
    }
}

var api = new Api();

api.Promise1().then(resultOfPromise1 =>
    resultOfPromise1 == "QOO" ?
        api.Promise2() :
        Promise.reject({ some: "errorInfo" })
).then(resultOfPromise2 => {
    console.log(resultOfPromise2);
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I'll take some time putting the full code on Github, with classified informations and logics cut off.

Comment: What's the definition of `api.Promise2()`?

Comment: api.Promise2() returns a new Promise too.

Comment: I've wrote an function doSqlQuery(string):Promise in api module and both api.Promise1() and api.Promise2() wraps doSqlQuery().
Is these info helping?

Comment: Not really, it is still not clear how `Promise2()` response look like. It would be much easier if you could reproduce the error on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: Looks like it could be branching issue: resultOfPromise1.isGood() ?
         api.Promise2() :
         Promise.reject({some:"errorInfo"}) if you reject the promise do you have a result object with "doSomething"

Comment: @MartinChaov IDTS, if the previous promise rejected then the resolve callback should not be called. But how the tsc recognizes it as a 'never' that's currently out of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting in the dark but can you try this:

```
npm i --save-dev  @types/es6-promise
```

and add:

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'
```